# Show a space below actions in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertcontroller

Versions of iOS prior to 8 allowed me to create a `UIActionsheet` which would show a group of buttons, some space, and then a cancel button.  Something like this:

[image: Desired Behavior]

However in iOS 8 when I try and create the same look I end up with something that looks like this:

[image: iOS 8 Behavior]

The code, in iOS 8 looks like this:

```
UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[alertVC.view setTintColor:[UIColor copperColor]];

UIAlertAction* notifyViaPush = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Send Alert to my phone"
                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
                            [alertVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                        }];
UIAlertAction* notifyViaEmail = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Notify me by email"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
                            [alertVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                        }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                 {
                                     [alertVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                 }];

[alertVC addAction:notifyViaPush];
[alertVC addAction:notifyViaEmail];
[alertVC addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**How can I group my buttons and have some space between the actions and cancel button using UIAlertController?**

Answer (score 9):

The line `alertVC.view.tintColor = [UIColor copperColor];` is causing problem, it makes the whole view of alert controller the same color, in your first picture the cancel button has white background. To fix this, move this line to the end of the function, that is, after you have added all actions.

Comment: This fixes the problem!  Can you help me understand why setting the tint color causes the whole view to end up grouped together?

Comment: For that you'll have to subclass a UIAlertController, the old style is this: <UIView: 0x7fa73bd7d540; frame = (0 0; 359 88); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa73bd89040>>,
<_UIAlertControllerActionView: 0x7fa73bdaf120; frame = (0 96; 359 44); Action = <UIAlertAction: 0x7fa73bd54700 Title = "Cancel" Descriptive = "(null)" Image = 0x0>>, it has a 12pt gap in between,which is clear color, setting tintcolor earlier seems to make the gap disappear, the new style has a collectionview with 3 cells, each height is 44.

Comment: The old style has a collectionview with 2 cells, and a gap, I am not sure how it happened. You might investigate more to come out an explanation.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me at all, but this works anyway. +1

Answer (score 7):

For me it worked when I set the style to `UIAlertActionStyleCancel` on the `UIAlertAction`.

In the code below, `action` is a `UIAlertAction` object and `controller` is a `UIAlertController` with style Action sheet.

```
UIAlertAction *action2 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
            self.tabBarView.selectedIndex = 1;
            [self.tabBarView setSelectedIndex:self.tabBarView.selectedIndex];
        }];
        [controller addAction:action];
        [controller addAction:action2];
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift Answer

Set the `style:` parameter of the action button that you want to separate to `.cancel` instead of `.default`.

like this `style: .cancel`

or more specifically this

```
// **style: on this is set to .cancel**
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in }
```

It's usually the button that you named "Cancel"

[image]

I'm not sure about how setting the button text colors the way the op said he did it in his answer affects the way the actions get separated. I use the actions "titleTextColor" to change the text color and it has no effect on the spacing the op is asking about.

```
cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.green, forKey: "titleTextColor")
```

Here's the code in 4 steps

```
func presentActionSheet() {
    
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // 1. style: is set to .default on both of these which will keep them grouped
    let blockAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Block", style: .default) { (action) in }
    let reportAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Report", style: .default) { (action) in }

    // 2. style: is set to .cancel which will separate it from the other two actions
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in }

    // 3. set the colors for the action text
    blockAction.setValue(UIColor.brown, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    reportAction.setValue(UIColor.purple, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.green, forKey: "titleTextColor")

    // 4. add the buttons to the action sheet and make sure the cancel button is last
    actionSheet.addAction(blockAction)
    actionSheet.addAction(reportAction)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```